# Apply to Only 1 current document FInd and change

Tags: applescript

Hi Below is apple script which does find and change operation in indesign document.But this script does not execute and gives a error.

> "Adobe InDesign CS6 got an error: Can’t set find text preferences of document 1 to nothing."

script is

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
  tell front document
    set find text preferences to nothing
    set change text preferences to nothing
--Letter Z--
    set case sensitive of find change text options to true
    set abbreviation to ".<005A>"
    set thinspace to ". <005A>"
    set find what of find text preferences to abbreviation
    set change to of change text preferences to thinspace
    change text
    set find text preferences to nothing
    set change text preferences to nothing
  end tell
end tell
```

Please suggest any one.

This should run for only for opened document. when front document is removed this script runs.

I could not sort out the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `find text preferences` and `change text preferences` belong to the application, not to a document. Try this

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
    if (count documents) is 0 then return
    set find text preferences to nothing
    set change text preferences to nothing

    set case sensitive of find change text options to true
    set abbreviation to ".<005A>"
    set thinspace to ". <005A>"
    set find what of find text preferences to abbreviation
    set change to of change text preferences to thinspace
    tell document 1
        change text
    end tell
    set find text preferences to nothing
    set change text preferences to nothing
end tell
```

Comment: You're welcome. If your question is answered, accept the answer